# VS code Include path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include

I was working on a small project on VS code, and it was all fine. Then I closed the program and opened it again later, all of the sudden my whole file is flooded with red error line, however, it compiles fine.

[image]

[image]

For some reason, if I reversed the order of the include files, the red lines goes away, and it looks okay, but I tried to go to any function declaration or definition (the std functions) eg. `std::rand`, it says that there is no declaration of definition.

It drives me crazy and I spend the last 3 hours trying to decrypt why in the hell is it doing that, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a "Clean" option on projects. This is rarely needed, but it throws away intermediate information from previous compilations. If that information is somehow outdated, you can get strange errors.

More specifically, what you're seeing is part of Intellisense. That's the Visual Studio component which live-compiles your code as you type, not to produce an executable but to show expected compilation errors when you do compile it to an executable. It's also the component which handles the "go to definition" feature.

Comment: I’m working on Visual Studio Code, not visual studio, sorry if that wasn’t clear.

Comment: @Abood: I realised that when I had written my answer, and then double-checked. VS Code also has Intellisense, for the same purpose. The notion of "cleaning" a build is even broader; it comes from the original UNIX `make`.